# Java Servlet 205 command not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm following the headfirst book about Servlets and JSP and I'm trying to make the first example in the book work for me as well.
However when I type in the command :

sh bin/startup.sh    (I'm using Windows )

I get an error

/bin/catalina.sh : line 205 : tty : command not found.
Even though this error occurs I still get about 5 more lines saying USING CATALINA_BASE ...

I tried to ignore the error to see if I can see the page but it tells me that the requested resource is not available. I'm using Tomcat 7.0.47

The place that I'm running the command from is my tomcat 7.0.47 folder.

Comment: When you type in the command in which place?

Comment: You shouldn't be running `catalina.sh` (or any other shell script, are you using cygwin?) in Windows. You should be using `startup.bat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

You are trying to execute a *nix command in a Windows environment.

Could you please give more details about what are you trying to do?